# Allow all commands via sudo but nopasswd for specific commands

Tags: linux, centos, sudo

I want to make sudo configuration such that one user 'test' should have access to all commands,all hosts like root. But for specific commands like 'ls /root' password should not get promted.

I'hv checked other questions but not able to find solution..Can someone please help?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You want that for some commands the  password is requested and not for others?

Comment: no, I want for some commands password should not be requested and should be rest of the commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a command alias for the commands which can be used without password:

```
Cmnd_Alias PASSWORDLESS = /bin/ls /root, /bin/whatever
```

Next add the user:

```
test ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

And finally add the rule for the commands which are allowed without password:

```
test ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: PASSWORDLESS
```

The order is important, the `NOPASSWD` line must be below the other rule for the user.